# Space between paragraphs - \parskip not working

Tags: overleaf, parskip

I realise this has been asked many, many times but I can't seem to find the right answer.

I (stupidly) decided to use the "MastersDoctoralThesis" template (I'm working in Overleaf) and now it's too late to change everything.

I'm trying to put an empty line between my paragraphs but I'm not getting anywhere. Paragraphs are starting on a new line, but there is no empty line between them.

In the template there is an option to include "parskip" (minimal example here)

```
\documentclass[
11pt, % The default document font size, options: 10pt, 11pt, 12pt
doublespacing, % Single line spacing, alternatives: onehalfspacing or doublespacing
parskip % Uncomment to add space between paragraphs
]
```

So I uncommented it (I can see in the background files that there's an "if parskip then require package blabla"). So parskip is loaded.

But when I try to compile there is no empty line between paragraphs.

So I tried using

```
\setlength\parskip{12pt plus 1em} % and multiple variations of spacing - even 24pt and one point.
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
```

Edit: I tried this both inside the

```
begin{document}
bla
end{document}
```

and outside of it

Still no luck.

I also tried commenting out the `parskip` in the `documentclass[]` and just including `\usepackage{parskip}` (no luck) and also tried to `\setlength` in that situation but no luck.

Help? Thesis due soon, panic setting in.

---

Example added by David C...

From https://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis

```
\documentclass[
11pt,
doublespacing,
parskip
]{MastersDoctoralThesis}

\setlength\parskip{30pt plus 5pt minus 5pt}
\begin{document}
aaa\\aaa

aaa\\aaa
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: What happens if you add `\setlength\parskip{12pt plus 1em}` right after `\begin{document}`?

Comment: Celdor's solution works, I tried it with the`MastersDoctoralThesis` class.

Comment: how are you separating paragraphs?

Comment: if `\parskip` is non zero and you have no gaps either something is setting it back, or you do not have paragraph breaks, as you have shown no code we can not say anything

Comment: I added an example but it shows a space between paragraphs, please edit it so that it shows your problem.